# Python convert date format to datetime accurately which includes dates before 1970

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, data-conversion

Consider python panda code as

```
datetest = pd.DataFrame({'year':['02','08',23,32,43,68,70,72,85,94]})
newdate = pd.to_datetime(datetest['year'], format='%y')
print(newdate)
```

Output:

```
0   2002-01-01
1   2008-01-01
2   2023-01-01
3   2032-01-01
4   2043-01-01
5   2068-01-01
6   1970-01-01
7   1972-01-01
8   1985-01-01
9   1994-01-01
Name: year, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

So how can I convert 2023, 2032, 2043, 2068 to 1923, 1932, 1943, 1968 respectively keeping datetime format intact?

Comment: how about preprocessing the data to use four digit years, then there wouldn't be any ambiguity?

Comment: @SamMason Yeah it can be done but given data is more complicated than this and also more string manipulations would require. Hence I was looking for cleaner solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do use boolean indexing and [`pandas.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) to adjust any dates in the future by 100 years.

If this rule is too strict, you can set your own threshold for what an acceptible year might be:

```
year = pd.datetime.today().year

# If setting your own threshold year eg.
# year = 2030

newdate.loc[newdate.dt.year.gt(year)] -= pd.DateOffset(years=100)
```

[out]

```
0   2002-01-01
1   2008-01-01
2   1923-01-01
3   1932-01-01
4   1943-01-01
5   1968-01-01
6   1970-01-01
7   1972-01-01
8   1985-01-01
9   1994-01-01
Name: year, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you, @Chris A